# Why is my intuition failing me in these cases?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, string

In cases where the string is rotating:
[image]

In both cases, the accelerations of both the masses along the direction of the string are different because one of them is undergoing rotation. I understand that.

But intuitively, the acceleration of two ends of a taut string along the string should be the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing which is constant about an inextensible string is its length, not its shape or orientation. There is nothing which requires both ends to have the same vector acceleration, even if it is kept taut.

With the origin at the hole or pulley, the radial acceleration of each end is $a_r=\ddot r -r\dot \theta^2$. The total length of string $r_1+r_2=$ constant, so $\ddot r_1=-\ddot r_2$. But there is nothing to prevent the ends from having different angular velocities $\dot \theta$, and therefore different radial accelerations $a_r$.

Comment: Yes, but in both these cases, one of the masses has a centripetal acceleration along the string while the other one is has no acceleration along the string.

Comment: In both cases, the length of the string is not changing : $\ddot r=\dot r=0$. The centripetal acceleration is $r\dot \theta^2$, which does not require the length of the string to change.